# How to allow users to use a custom top level domain as their profile URL?

Tags: apache, dns, server, tld

I have a site where users have profile URL's like `www.site.com/username123`. I want to provide a feature so they can use a TLD like `www.username123.com` to point to their profile.

Tumblr does exactly what I want (screenshot below):

[image: Tumblr feature]

I want to understand how to do this. Assuming that I'm using PHP and Apache:

1. What kind of server do I need? Can I use shared hosting?
2. What configs do I need to do in order for this to work?
3. What DNS record the user must create to put things together?